# Devexpress Grid control throwing Object refrence not set to an instance of an object when pressing tab

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, gridcontrol, object-reference

The exception is thrown after an in-place editor of a cell is `validated`, as both rows and cells lose focus (this is the main problem that I am looking to solve):

**Getting to the bug**

I give in input a value to the `RepositoryItemTextEdit`, for example an `Id`, then check if it exists in the database and return the full object containing that Id, so I catch the `sender` as `TextEdit` and place the `returned object` in its `EditValue` property. What happens next is that both cells and rows get **unfocused** for some reason, 
so if I press **TAB** key the above mentioned exception is thrown (I think it doesn't find anything to focus so that's the main problem), else if I *manually* select a cell and then press **TAB** the exception won't be thrown.

```
private void OnRepositoryPartitariValidating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var objConto = gridView.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Conto");
        if (((sender as TextEdit).EditValue) is Partitario) return;
        var codice = (sender as TextEdit).EditValue.ToString();
        var partitario = Partitario.Manager.GetByCodice(codice);
        if (partitario == null)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            if (objConto is Conto)
                using (ListPartitari form = new ListPartitari((Conto)objConto))
                {

                    form.FnOk += delegate (object item)
                    {
                        if (item is Partitario)
                        {
                            (sender as TextEdit).EditValue = item;

                            e.Cancel = false;
                        }
                    };
                    form.ShowDialog(this);
                }
            else
                using (ListPartitari form = new ListPartitari())
                {

                    form.FnOk += delegate (object item)
                    {
                        if (item is Partitario)
                        {
                            (sender as TextEdit).EditValue = item;
                            e.Cancel = false;
                        }
                    };
                    form.ShowDialog(this);
                }
        }
        else
        {
            (sender as TextEdit).EditValue = partitario;
            //if (partitario.Conto.Id != ((Conto)objConto).Id)
            //    gridView.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Conto", partitario.Conto);

        }
    }
```

This is the stacktrace of the error: https://pastebin.com/yNx7MLhe

Exception details: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDPS6.jpg

Comment: This sounds like a big, maybe you should ask on the DevExpress forum

Comment: DevExpress support is amazing. Do that. They will likely say to handle the validating event on the gridview rather than the repositoryitem. See https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114741/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Getting-Started/Walkthroughs/Data-Editing/Tutorial-Data-Input-Validation

Comment: @TheGeneral I am using a trial version of Dev express at the moment, so I won't consider contacting their support until I'll upgrade to premium. I've added some details to the question, may you check them

Comment: I've seen an error like this a lot in my time and it can be hard to pin down. After you tab away from the cell in the grid i'd say its  making some kind of callback to the server. Callbacks can be funny old things in that they can run the full page life cycle every time they are made
I've seen other controls on page cause this error within the grid that had nothing to do with what was happening. 
Having said that try to imagine what context might not be met in that scenario and work from there.

Do you inherit the gridview class with your own methods on top? that's also worth looking at.